# Adobe Brackets highlight declared variables?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm using **brackets.io**. I find it annoying that it does not highlight defined variables and functions. for example, unlike this picture.

[image: picture]

I want `myVar` to be highlighted in the second line, showing that it has been defined. Similarly with functions. I have not been able to find a way to do this in brackets, either natively or with an extension.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me thinks this here is a simple matter of **themes**. i.e;
Your var **HAS** been highlighted, but it just so happens that the 'highlight-color' for that particular string type is white, as styled in your current theme. Just install another one and you'll be set.

Ways/options to get them[*in case you didn't know how*]:

1. Search & Install (direct) via File > Extension Manager > Themes.
2. Search google for '*brackets themes*' OR '*dark brackets theme*' etc,
   find, download and then install it manually.
3. Browse/Peruse through this site here
   https://brackets-themes.github.io/. See one that's to your liking?
   Download and then install manually.

***PS:*** I prefer and use option 2 coz **A**, you have an almost endless *list*, ranging from *official releases* to *random personal user created ones*, from which you could choose., and **B**, you have a visual idea of how the theme looks before downloading, courtesy of Google Images and you are thus more likely to get one that tickles your fancy.

There maybe some other ways not mentioned (idk), but I'd suggest you start with any of these first. If still not satisfied, you could just create your own. Broken down, the process is pretty straight forward as it's just basically(if I may) HTML & CSS.

Cheers mate, happy coding!